# GUI Dialog on a separate thread

Tags: wxwidgets

are there any objects when running wxWidget's common dialogs on a separate thread? I'm developing a browser plugin and so I need to put lengthy operations outside the main browser thread.

I did a small test and it seems to work but a warning appears:

....\src\msw\dirdlg.cpp(333): 'CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog)' failed with error 0x800401f0 (coInitialize has not been called.).

Does that mean I have to call wxApp::Initialize(...) or some other functions?

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call [CoInitialize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in [each thread](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=784) where you are using COM. So before creating common dialog objects just call CoInitialize() (one per thread) and in the end of thread call [CoUninitialize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688715%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For main thread wxWidgets does this internally. For other threads you'll need to call these functions manually. It is generally not related to GUI but related to COM objects which wxWidgets uses internally.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Can you tell whether or not there are objections in running wxWidget Dialog on a separate thread?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are 'objections'

> **Important notes for multithreaded applications**
>
> When writing a multi-threaded application, it is strongly recommended
>   that no secondary threads call GUI functions.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_thread.html

Comment: Ok, I got that. I only plan on showing some basic dialogs on a separate thread. That seems to work. The GUI itself wont be multi-threaded.

Comment: I'm not sure you get it. Some native dialogs may work under MSW but not all of them will. And I'm all but sure that none at all will work under the other platforms. "Seems to work" is really not a good criterion of determining correctness of multi-threaded programs.

Comment: There was a sample of multi-threaded GUI app at official forums. Probably this topic: http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=8392.